# How to make a PostgreSQL table real-time?

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart, chat

I want to develop a flutter chat application using PostgreSQL database. I am using Laravel for the web.

I do not want to use firebase.

Comment: How is a regular PostgreSQL table not real-time?

Comment: What's your understanding of a real-time table as opposed to a regular PostgreSQL table? If you just want PostgreSQL to accommodate the exchange of messages, you can look into [`LISTEN`/`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html). If you also want to save all chats, you can just add a passive listener that saves messages to a table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use WebSocket for broadcasting
see this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#configuration)